# How is Special Relativity (SR) shown to NOT be an artifact of perception or measurement

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Special Relativity ([SR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity)) paradoxes are old-hat. But as I read explanations, they tend to resolve issues of simultaneity by applying the appropriate math... but that seems to me to be proving the theory by positing the theory.  Just because the math is valid doesn't mean an argument is sound.  All I have to do is believe warping space and time against curves and yes... it all works out.

For instance... A space ship is traveling toward an asteroid and away from a stationary body at 60 percent the speed of light while at the same time an asteroid is traveling directly toward the space ship and toward the stationary body at 60 percent the speed of light.

So the typical question is, "when does the space ship meet its demise?... distance / (1.2*c)?"  *My question is distinctly different.*  Why is it we are confident that the conclusion matches reality... i.e. how do we know the space ship doesn't just blow up before it thought it should based on only the perception and measurements available to it which seem to be governed by SR?

Comment: *So if it were argued that SR is [...] an accurate model of distortion in measurements, but not reality... how is this argument debunked reasonably or experimentally?* All physical theories are models that are constructed to give accurate predictions of measurements. Whether you take that as meaning they describe "reality" would depend on your definition of "reality."

Comment: @BenCrowell I removed the offending paragraph. Do you have any more constructive criticism?

Comment: @BenCrowell so if I live in my own crazy reality, physical theories have no bearing on reality. Yes! I absolutely agree with your statement

Comment: @BenCrowell I fail to see why this is on hold when at least one person clearly understands my question and provided helpful insight and a specific example. What specifically is unclear about this question so I can fix it and get your thoughts? Disdain is not an acceptable argument from what I understand of science, which seems to be your major contribution thus far.

Comment: @cocogorilla: the predictions of SR match experiment - it's one of the best tested theories we have, and it's an essential part of QFT which is responsible for the best match to experiment ever achieved (1 part in 1,000,000,000,000). You seem to be asking how we know the spaceship doesn't really blow up even though every experimental measurement we make on it matches the predictions of SR. I don't see how we can answer this.

Comment: @JohnRennie well you're doing a fine job helping me narrow in on my question.  You say there is a large body of experimental evidence... I have no doubt there is.  Would it help if I asked what rational is used in the top two experiments that provides confidence they are NOT false positives?  I'm seeking to understand the logic that eliminates/diminishes the possibility for simple error in SR experimentation.

Comment: @cocogorilla: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity, http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/experiments.html, http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0506168, etc, etc

Comment: @JohnRennie your math.ucr.edu link is fantastic. Numerous experiments or observations setup in the way I'm looking for, "if SR were not true we would expect X" and then knock it down by observing Y which ends up consistent with SR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general answer is *"We engineer things with relativity."*

The most striking example I know is the CEBAF accelerator at JLAB.

Like all modern accelerators it uses RF linacs to add energy to the beam. That only works if the size of the cavities and the frequency of the RF match the speed of beam.

Now, CEBAF is special, beams of widely differing energy can propagate simultaneously through the linac at high efficiency, which only works because the speed of the beam is insensitive to the kinetic energy in the ultra-relativistic regime in which the machine works.

Pre-upgrade a 50 MeV beam could coexist with a 4.5 GeV beam. Post upgrade those numbers will roughly double.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question. Maybe this is a case where bad questions give rise to bad answers. The OP admits that SR works in practice, but wants to know whether that's "reality."

Comment: Contrary to @BenCrowell, this does address my question. If the engineering of physical machines that 'work' depends on SR, then SR works. I appreciated the specific example and the argument.

Comment: @cocogorilla not that I disagree with the acceptance of SR, but the fact that we can engineer things that work and depend on SR does not imply that SR works. It implies that either SR works or there is some unknown physical process that that either closely resembles the predictions of SR in part or that incorporates SR as a special case. But most likely it's that SR works

Comment: @Jim, yes... but the that's a distinction I'm not worried about here... I'm only interested in where confidence in SR comes from.  Having to engineer things that won't work unless you apply SR lends significant weight and is helpful to my understanding.